# Custome Page Number (Footer) in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a single tab spreadsheet. When I go for print preview, I see total of 10 pages.
If I insert footer and use page numbers, I see from page 1 to page 10.
Is it possible to customize this page numbering system? I want to see the page numbers displayed from page 4 to page 10. The first 3 pages should not display the page numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways I'm aware of to go about it.

1. Put your first 3 pages on a different worksheet (tab). Start the numbering of the other pages at 4.
2. Use a cell for the footer.
3. Use VBA to alter the page footers before printing the workbook.

It just depends on what's easiest for you.